# im getting build error after connecting firebase with my code

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Im getting the gollowing error when i add "com.google.gms.google-services" in build.gradle(app).

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method setVariantDir() for arguments [debug] on task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' of type com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add this into your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and do you have the proper implementations on your gradle? @Gokula kirshnan

Comment: change class path to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'`